# Why doesn't savedialog execute twice in a row?

Tags: delphi

I created a new application with Delphi 6 on XP.  I dropped the savedialog component on the main form along with a button component.  I edited the button handler to:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
savedialog1.FileName := 'test';
if savedialog1.Execute then showmessage('hit 1');
savedialog1.FileName := 'hold' + savedialog1.FileName;
if savedialog1.Execute then showmessage('hit 2');
end;
```

If I run and click "Save" in the first save dialog, the second save dialog never appears.  If I click "Cancel" in the first save dialog, the second save dialog appears.  If I change the concat to

```
savedialog1.FileName := 'holdtest';
```

the second dialog appears whether I save or cancel the first dialog.  What's going on?

Comment: `hold + SaveDialog1.FileName` is probably something like `holdC:\test.txt` which is an invalid file name, and this might cause the dialog not to show (just guessing, can't reproduce). Probably, what you want is `hold + ExtractFileName(SaveDialog1.FileName)` which will yield `holdtest.txt`.

Comment: In my rush, I forgot FileName is one of those weird properties that doesn't read back what you just wrote.  (Component designers take note: something like "FileName" should stay as written, and another property named something like "FullPath" would be a better place to send out the modified string.)  Still, SaveDialog would be a lot better if a bad filename didn't prevent the dialog from appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andreas suggests in his comment, the issue is the setting of the **Filename** property before presenting the dialog the second time (which I have reproduced and confirmed in Delphi 7).

The **FileName** property returns the fully qualified filename so this assignment:

```
SaveDialog1.Filename := 'hold' + SaveDialog1.Filename;
```

results in a **Filename** property with a value similar to:

```
holdC:\foo.txt
```

This is not a valid filename so when the **SaveDialog** component attempts to invoke the common dialog with this setting, that fails.  Unfortunately the **SaveDialog** component does not trap this and report the error, it simply results in the **Execute** method immediately returning `FALSE` without presenting any dialog to the user.

Since the function returns `FALSE`, your second **ShowMessage()** is not called.

## Possible Solutions

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve here, but Andreas suggestion of using **ExtractFilename()** is one way of avoiding the problem:

```
SaveDialog1.Filename := 'hold' + ExtractFilename(SaveDialog1.Filename);
```

However, if the intention was to retain the path information and modify the filename part then you could set **InitialDir** separately from the **Filename** (as above):

```
SaveDialog1.Filename := 'hold' + ExtractFilename(SaveDialog1.Filename);
SaveDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(SaveDialog1.Filename);
```

Or alternatively you could set the fully qualified **Filename** with a more verbose manipulation:

```
SaveDialog1.Filename := ExtractFilePath(SaveDialog1.Filename) + 'hold' + ExtractFilename(SaveDialog1.Filename);
```

Which of these is most appropriate in your case only you can decide.

**NOTE:** It appears that some change in the implementation in some later version of Delphi has partially resolved this problem since the identical code in Delphi XE4 does present the save dialog twice.  However, the invalid filename is retained as the default, despite being invalid.

So if your intention was to manipulate the filename and/or path in some way then even in any later version of Delphi you will need to apply one or other of the techniques above for correctly modifying the path/filename properties of the dialog.